# Use MongoClient pooling without embedding server.listen() in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use a single pool of MongoDB connections for a nodescript that runs a couple of services on two ports.

From the tutorials online, the one way to use pooled connections is:

```
...
var mongoClient = new MongoClient.connect("mongodb://user:pwd@server:port", function (err, db) {
  //Program here
  server.listen(8081);
});
...
```

Is there a methodology allows me to use a pool, while using the server.listen event outside the mongoClient function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try reuse/export database/collection variables.
Full example is available here: http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/11/deep-dive-into-connection-pooling/

Comment: Cheers for the link. However, this tutorial reiterates that a connection be made prior to the app responding.

I would like to run the code regardless of the Mongo connection status, and keep providing other services, such as program based calculators, even if the database is unavailable.

Comment: That was not very clear from the original question though. In this case you might want to check out promises (e.g. [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) or even something like promise wrapper for mongo driver such as [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin). There is also a bunch of examples already discussed here like http://stackoverflow.com/a/23597225/1808209