# Trying to understand how to use Promise in js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm using the native driver for mongoDB. In the db I have about 7 collections and I want create a variable that stores the amount of entries in each collection minus the last collection. Afterwards I want to create another variable that stores the entries of the last collection then I want to pass the variables through the res.render() command and show it on the webpage.

The problem I'm having here is that I'm so used to synchronous execution of functions which in this case goes straight out the window.

The code below is the way I'm thinking, if everything is executed in sync.

```
var count = 0;
db.listCollections().toArray(function(err,collection){
   for(i = 1; i < collection.length;i++){
      db.collection(collection[i].name).count(function(err,value){
         count = count + value;
      })
   }
   var count2 = db.collection(collection[i].name).count(function(err,value){
         return value;
      })
   res.render('index.html',{data1: count, data2: count2})
})
```

Obviously this doesn't do want I want to do so I tried playing around with promise, but ended up being even more confused.

Comment: I'm missing a specific question? Or do you want to have the code "fixed"?

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597059/promise-and-nodejs-mongodb-driver) or instead of using promises you can nest each call in the callback function, but promises will make you much happier in the long run.

Comment: Well I guess I want the code "fixed". But getting some kind of hints would obviously help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this with Promises:

Get collection names, iterate over them, and return either count, or entries (if it's the last collection). Then sum up individual counts and send everything to the client.

```
db.listCollections().toArray()
    .then(collections => {
        let len = collections.length - 1
        return Promise.all(collections.map(({name}, i) => {
          let curr = db.collection(name)
          return i < len ? curr.count() : curr.find().toArray()
        }
        ))
      }
    )
    .then(res => {
      let last = res.pop(),
          count = res.reduce((p, c) => p + c)
      res.render('index.html', {count, last})
    })
```

Comment: I'll look at it. There are some commands I've never used so I have to read up on it.

Comment: If I may ask. ({name},i) what does that equal to?  From what I can tell it's the same as making a for loop with i as iterator and where name represents the elements in collections? Or does the name represent the data in the name column in the json data?

Comment: Works now, had to first update node.js, had version 0.2.7!  Also had to use list.shift() to remove the first redundant collection name; system.indexes. Then i had to change ({name},i) to (name,i). Otherwise awesome! Thank you!

Comment: ({name},... ) is es6 object destructuring. Ex.

var object = {key: 'value'}

// this equals to...
var key = object.key

// this
var {key} = object

Comment: You can read more about destructuring [here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html)